# Beer Batter - let it rest before using or use immediately?

Tags: frying, deep-frying, batter, beer

I just purchased a deep fryer and have been looking at different recipes for making beer batter.  I noticed that some instruct you to let the batter sit for a number of hours before using it to coat veggies, meats, etc., while others do not mention this.  Does letting the batter rest make a difference in the flavor, texture, or anything else significant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it changes the texture.  If you want it light, you need to use it quickly, as the bubbles will disappate over time.

Comment: Does this mean that if you let the mixture rest for a few hours you will end up with a thicker/denser breading?  Does one or the other result in a crispier coating?

Comment: @Brando : It'll be denser, but not necessarily thicker by waiting. If you want a thicker coating, you're better off using a little less liquid so that it's a more viscous batter.  And it'll be crisper if you use it quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Probably use it quickly, I would think...

Comment: SmartCookie, welcome to the site. Your answer lacks an explanation as to why that would be so. Please edit your answer.